# I have been assigned a project for currency exchange rate IN SQL . How to save exchange rates for currencies?

Tags: sql

I Have to create a table currencies

```
CREATE TABLE currencies (
       from_currency        CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
       ExchRate             REAL NOT NULL,
       to_currency          CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (from_currency),
       FOREIGN KEY (to_currency) REFERENCES currencies(from_currency)
)
```

I have to save exchange rate for 6 currencies: (inr,eur,cad,usd,gbp,cfp)
But the problem is i can't store same values in first column
i.e.
I can save my currency rate as follow

```
from_curr      ER --> to_curr 
INR        --> 60 -->   USD
USD        --> 0  -->   USD
GBP        --> 70 -->   USD
```

e.t.c. for all the currencies but now the problem is while i try to store the currency for other er like

```
INR        --> 1  -->   USD
or
GBP        --> 70 -->   USD
```

I get error duplicates values are not allowed ?
How to solvve this problem ?

Comment: As a side note, you probably shouldn't be storing the exchange rate as a `REAL`, as it's a floating-point value.  Among other things, the value stored will most likely _not_ be the value entered, and people tend to get all kinds of twitchy about sums of money.  Because you should be storing any money amounts in something based off `NUMERIC`/`DECIMAL` types, you should be converting to that type for all operations regardless.  Save yourself some common conversion time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either create a composite primary key as a pair of 2 currencies is uniquely identifying a record for you.

```
CREATE TABLE currencies (
   from_currency        CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
   ExchRate             REAL NOT NULL,
   to_currency          CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (from_currency, to_currency)
)
```

Or alternatively you can add a new column for the primary key, e.g. as autoincrement column:

```
CREATE TABLE currencies (
   [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
   from_currency        CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
   ExchRate             REAL NOT NULL,
   to_currency          CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not storing a currency, but rather a pair of currencies.

```
CREATE TABLE currency_exchange_rates (
       from_currency        CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
       to_currency          CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
       ExchRate             REAL NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (from_currency,to_currency),
)
```

I would also suggest a separate table holding the six currencies and linking the table above to ensure valid currency codes.   You might also want to hold a date field (and make it part of the primary key), since rates can change over time...

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can't. That's because you defined `PRIMARY KEY ()`. Thus only distinct value is allowed for this column. What you need instead is that pairs of from_currency/to_currency are unique. You can do this by defining a composite PK in your table:

```
CREATE TABLE currencies (
       from_currency        CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
       ExchRate             REAL NOT NULL,
       to_currency          CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (from_currency, to_currency)
)
```